# create 3D map with octomap

Tags: ros, mapping, octomap, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to create a 3d map from environment with simulated kinect. i know that i should use from octomap, i want to get data of kinect and every where that yellow color is available,  set probability for it +1 and other places -1, any one can give me some hints or explain for me what should i do?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92681/create-3d-map-with-octomap/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-10-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2013-10-24**:
I am not able to understand much of your question, but one thing that seems strange is that you set probabilities to 1 and -1. First, a probability can never be negative and second, an octomap cell can never have probability 1 as far as I know. Try the defaults of 0.85 for occupied and 0.4 for free

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2013-10-24**:
Yes, you are right, i didn't consider this fact about probability. you know now i got data from simulated kinect and i can find yellow color, but i can't understand how can i use from octomap to create a 3d occupency grid map, in simple word i have technical problem and also i couldn't find any example in internet, i read this link http://octomap.sourceforge.net/doxygen/index.html, but i need a example or some hints to do next part, if you have any experience about it please give me some hints.

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2013-10-25**:
have you seen that there is an octomap rospackage:
http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server
i think you should start with this. if you need to customize the code, this could be helpful:
[http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~hornunga/pub/hornung13roscon.pdf](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ehornunga/pub/hornung13roscon.pdf)

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2013-10-25**:
Thank you, yes i should customize the code. but i can't find a step by step tutorial about this. by the way now i am starting to reading code. also my ros is hydro but i don't have octomap_server package, also i checked in computer of one of my friends also he didn't have this package.

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2013-10-25**:
thank you, i installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check here for octomap_server in hydro: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/octomap/kag-AqV6fYs/Jq3SG9cq32EJ

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0